# How to not consider free items when calculating shipping costs?

Tags: magento, shopping-cart

In my shop shipping is free on orders over $75.

I want to add a free item **A** to the cart when the customer purchases a specific product **B**.

Item **A** is set to be free of charge by:

```
 quoteItem->setOriginalCustomPrice(0);
```

This works fine so far. But for the calculation of the shipping costs still the original price of **A** is used. As a result, shipping is free when the original price of **A** and the price of **B** add up to be over $75.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: What about creating a free shipping price rule ... http://www.immense.net/magento-free-shipping-certain-products/

Comment: Nice article. I will keep this in mind for later use but its not what I am looking for since item A is also available separately and then shipping costs are needed.

Comment: Finally found the answer: For Magento 1.4.1.1 and above you need to set $quoteItem->setCustomPrice(0); and    $quoteItem->setOriginalCustomPrice(0); to get the right shipping cost.

Answer (score 0):

As @cads mentioned in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13708334/how-to-not-consider-free-items-when-calculating-shipping-costs#comment19172938_13708334):

For Magento 1.4.1.1 and above you need to set `$quoteItem->setCustomPrice(0);` and `$quoteItem->setOriginalCustomPrice(0);` to get the right shipping cost.